# Must both xlrd and xlsxwriter be a up-to-date version to capable transfer cell values from .XLSX files?

Tags: python, excel

Must both xlrd and xlsxwriter be of a minimally recent version capable of working upon .xlsx files? I  am using respective versions of:  xlrd 0.7.4 and xlsxwriter 0.6.0. In a python script file seeking to gather values from 3 worksheets within an .XLSX file and return summed values in a single sheet output .xlsx file, the script reads as

```html
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import csv
import os
from os import walk
import glob
import shutil
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


os.chdir('S:\\Projects\\CMP\\DataCollectorsWiki\\ArchiveofWork\\ITC_2007_Group1')
root = 'S:\\Projects\\CMP\\DataCollectorsWiki\\ArchiveofWork\\ITC_2007_Group1'
allfiles = [os.path.join(root,f) for root, dirs, files in walk(root) for f in files]

##consolidate all sheets from data workbooks
for afile in allfiles:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(afile)
    passenger = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    hvyTruck = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
    ltTruck = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)
```

Again, I am using respective versions of:  xlrd 0.7.4 and xlsxwriter 0.6.0.  I have read that it is only the xlrd version 0.9.0 that is able to read .xlsx (Excel2007) or subsequent.  Additionally, I have noticed that the .xlsx files I have been working with - when opened in Notepad - begin with either DI or PK - (PK's are actually ZIP files, I've found out).

So my 2 questions are -

1.must both the xlrd and xlsxwriter be both of a certain vintage (version) to properly extract cell value data from .XLSX files and/or:

2. can the .xlsx files that begin with "PK" be changed in some way not to have that condition - or is saving back to .xls (Excel '97) encouraged before running the Python script?

Answer (score 0):

> So my 2 questions are...

1. Yes, the minimum version of xlrd must be at least 0.9.0 (as you say yourself) to read xlsx files. It is probably best to use the latest version of xlrd since it will also contain bug fixes. The XlsxWriter module writes files so you don't need any version of that to extract data from an Excel file. If you want to write an xlsx file then any version of XlsxWriter will do but the latest version has more features and bug fixes.
2. It isn't easy to convert xlsx to xls with 100% fidelity outside of Excel.

So if you have a choice between trying to automate Excel on Windows to convert files from one format to another or just upgrading xlrd to a more recent version then the latter seems easier.